# Tag everytime a member appears again as circulated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to tag circulations, that is everytime a member appears again.
This list shows the result I want

```
Sequence ID Aktivity ID From, Agent ID  To, Agent ID    Movement    Circulated
1           001A9552444 YNGBAN          TOMYAN          1           0
2           001A9552461 TOMYAN          THOKIN          1           0
3           001A9552466 THOKIN          MATLOV          1           0
4           001A9552486 MATLOV          THOKIN          1           1
5           001A9552499 THOKIN          YNGBAN          1           1
6           001A9554213 YNGBAN          IKJER           1           0
```

Code for creating base table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Basetable]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Basetable] (
[Incident ID] INT,
[Activity ID] VARCHAR(50),
[Agent ID] VARCHAR(50),
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basetable]
VALUES
(1072326, '001A9552444', 'YNGBAN'),
(1072326, '001A9552461', 'TOMYAN'),
(1072326, '001A9552463', 'THOKIN'),
(1072326, '001A9552464', 'THOKIN'),
(1072326, '001A9552465', 'THOKIN'),
(1072326, '001A9552466', 'THOKIN'),
(1072326, '001A9552468', 'MATLOV'),
(1072326, '001A9552484', 'MATLOV'),
(1072326, '001A9552485', 'MATLOV'),
(1072326, '001A9552486', 'MATLOV'),
(1072326, '001A9552499', 'THOKIN'),
(1072326, '001A9554212', 'YNGBAN'),
(1072326, '001A9554213', 'YNGBAN'),
(1072326, '001A9568252', 'IKJER')
```

Below is the code so far. I don't want to do Group By and Count and have tried Left Join and Outer Apply but haven't found a good solution yet.

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Activity ID]) AS [Sequence ID]
   ,[Incident ID]
   ,[Activity ID]
   ,[From, Agent ID]
   ,[To, Agent ID] 
   ,1 AS [Movement]
FROM (
   SELECT
         [Incident ID]
         ,[Activity ID]
         ,[Agent ID] AS [From, Agent ID] 
         ,LEAD([Agent ID],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Incident ID] ORDER BY [Activity ID]) AS [To, Agent ID] 
   FROM [dbo].[Basetable]
   ) AS X
WHERE
   [To, Agent ID] != '0' AND [From, Agent ID] != [To, Agent ID]
)
SELECT
   X1.[Sequence ID]
   ,X1.[Incident ID]
   ,X1.[Activity ID]
   ,X1.[From, Agent ID]
   ,X1.[To, Agent ID] 
   ,X1.[Movement]
FROM X AS X1
```

Edit: added code for creating base table and cleaned up the main code.

Comment: Which of these columns is member? It would be useful if you could include sample data as well as required result.

Comment: The two Agent fields contain the members. I have now added code for creating sample data. The required result is shown at the very start.

Comment: what is the logic for `Circulated` ?

Comment: The logic for Circulated: In the ordered sequence, if a [To, Agent ID] has appeared earlier as an [From, Agent DI] then Circulated = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Your existing query
;WITH X AS (
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Activity ID]) AS [Sequence ID]
   ,[Incident ID]
   ,[Activity ID]
   ,[From, Agent ID]
   ,[To, Agent ID] 
   ,1 AS [Movement]
FROM (
   SELECT
         [Incident ID]
         ,[Activity ID]
         ,[Agent ID] AS [From, Agent ID] 
         ,LEAD([Agent ID],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Incident ID] ORDER BY [Activity ID]) AS [To, Agent ID] 
   FROM [dbo].[Basetable]
   ) AS X
WHERE
   [To, Agent ID] != '0' AND [From, Agent ID] != [To, Agent ID]
),
Y AS
(
SELECT
   X1.[Sequence ID]
   ,X1.[Incident ID]
   ,X1.[Activity ID]
   ,X1.[From, Agent ID]
   ,X1.[To, Agent ID] 
   ,X1.[Movement]
FROM X AS X1
)
-- Added this part
SELECT  Y.*, CASE WHEN Z.CNT > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Circulated
FROM    Y
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Count the occurrence of the To Agent ID appear before as `From`
        SELECT  CNT = COUNT(*)
        FROM    X
        WHERE   X.[Sequence ID]     < Y.[Sequence ID]
        AND     X.[From, Agent ID]  = Y.[To, Agent ID]
    ) Z
```